# 100 BASE Tx Ethernet question

Tags: voltage, current, ethernet, bandwidth, phy

I am going through this Wikipedia article - [Fast Ethernet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Ethernet) and got this below table.

[image]

1. Can someone please explain why there are 3 line codes : 4B5B, MLT3 and NRZ-I done? Why all 3 are done?
2. Also can someone tell me how the calculation of Symbol rate per land and bandwidth is done?

Answer (score 2):

4B5B maps 4 bit sequences and controls to five bit sequences that also guarantee that there are sufficient transitions in the signal, even with a stream of all zeros or all ones.

NRZI is used at one stage of transmission on the way to the media dependent sublayer, but the final encoding on the Ethernet cable is MLT3.

From the Fast Ethernet [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Ethernet#100BASE-TX):

> The 4B5B encoding provides DC equalization and spectrum shaping. Just as in the 100BASE-FX case, the bits are then transferred to the physical medium attachment layer using NRZI encoding. However, 100BASE-TX introduces an additional, medium dependent sublayer, which employs MLT-3 as a final encoding of the data stream before transmission, resulting in a maximum fundamental frequency of 31.25 MHz.

The calculation is done as follows:

100 Mbit/sec of raw data becomes 125 Mbit/sec (symbol rate) of 4b5b encoded data. MLT3 ensures that four bits are required for a complete cycle from low to high and back, making the maximum fundamental frequency of 125/4 MHz = 31.25 MHz. Of course, harmonics of this frequency can and will exist on the wire.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But what purpose does NRZ-I and MLT-3 serve individually?

Comment: Why do we need two encoding techniques back to back (i.e., NRZ-I and MLT-3)?

Comment: @Newbie NRZI is used between the PMA (physical medium attachment) and PMD (physical medium dependent) sublayer, which may exist on separate chips of a Fast Ethernet network card. MLT-3 is used on the medium itself. Have a look at https://training.ti.com/sites/default/files/docs/ti_precision_labs_-_ethernet_anatomy_of_the_phy.pdf for more details on the sublayers of the phy.

Comment: I'm still unable to understand, could you please explain in simpler terms

Comment: @Newbie In the network card, the PMA deals with timing and line coding (4b5b), while the PMD actually creates the correct voltage levels, drive impedances, etc for the cable. When transmitting, the signal from the PMA to the PMD is NRZI, and the 100BASE-TX specific PMD converts it  to MLT3. When receiving, the PMD converts the MLT3 to NRZI which is received and decoded by the PMA. There are other PMDs available - you can put 100 Mbit into a fiber with a PMD that contains lasers and photodiodes.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So, its the standard that is set like that which requires both NRZ-I and MLT-3, right? I'm extremely sorry to ask this question again - But why does the standard require both NRZ-I and then MLT-3? Isn't one encoding sufficient enough?

Comment: @Newbie Because the NRZI encoding isn't for the medium. It serves a completely different purpose altogether. It's the encoding that was chosen to get the signal over a distance of a few centimeters between the PMA to the PMD. It's a simple encoding, suitable for that distance, while the PMD actually transmits a signal (electrical or optical) which is specifically tailored for the medium (twisted pair or fiber).

Comment: I'm still not clear on why we need to do NRZI between the PMA to PMD. I assume PMA and PMD are within the PHY (IC) block itself. If so, why doesn't MLT-3 encoding suffice between PMA and PMD and then to the outer world?

Comment: @Newbie that's not a correct assumption. The PMA and PMD *may* be separate ICs to meet design needs, and when they are, NRZI is used as the *standardized* encoding between them, even if they are made by different manufacturers.

Comment: Oh, but please tell then why NRZI is required? Why MLT-3 alone does not suffice? What advantage or disadvantage is there ?

Comment: @Newbie MLT3 is a more complex waveform requiring more complex circuitry to encode and decode. It's only applicable for twisted pair Ethernet, not fiber. Its purpose is to shape the signal for the twisted pair Ethernet cable medium. Why should a 100BASE-FX (optical fiber) PMD deal with its higher complexity? Why should the PMA pay the complexity price to use it if the signal is only going a few inches to a fiber PMD?

Answer (score 2):

Your topic says about gigabit Ethernet but ask about 100Base-TX.

1. First the 100Mbps data is grouped to 4-bit symbols of which are then expanded to 5-bit symbols using 4b5b coding, resulting into 125 Mbps bit stream. Then the NRZ-I coding just means that only logic 1 bits make MLT-3 encoder state advance to next step and logic 0 bits have no effect. The MLT-3 encoder will sequence through the three output voltage levels in sequence, which has four states - positive, zero, negative, zero.
2. As already said 4b5b encoding makes the 100Mbps bit rate to equal 125 Mbps in encoded form. And since the MLT-3 output basically generates a digital sine waveform with four samples per cycle, the bandwidth can be calculated as 125Mbps/4 = 31.25 MHz as the maximum sine wave frequency that can be generated.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you tell me why is NRZ-I and MLT-3 both are done? Why cannot we go with only one?

Comment: Why do we need two encoding techniques back to back (i.e., NRZ-I and MLT-3)?

Comment: Because that's how the hierarchy works in the standard. The NRZ-I encoded data can be sent over to fiber interface as done in 100Base-FX, but in 100Base-TX copper interface it must be MLT-3 encoded to reduce the bandwidth to be able to send it over Cat5 cabling.

Comment: Could you please give a simpler explanation ? Still unable to understand

Comment: Simpler explanation of what exactly? What specifically you don't understand?

Comment: I read that NRZ-I and MLT-3 are encoding techniques for security purposes. My doubt why can't you just encode the signal with only one technique, either NRZ-I or MLT-3? Why does ethernet does 4b/5b, then scramble, NRZ-I and then MLT-3 ?

Comment: @Newbie They're *not* for security purposes. They're line codes necessary from a signal integrity and electrical requirements standpoint, which map a digital signal (of abstract '0' and '1') bits into actual waveforms with voltages, transitions, and other similar considerations.

Comment: They are not for security. They are required to shape the signal properties to be able to transmit it over limited bandwidth cables.

Comment: Oh, so NRZ-I and MLT-3 are not for security purposes? I thought encoding of the data is done so that it is not understood by the person inbetween the transmission stage. But still, if they are required to meet the signal integrity and electrical requirements, why don't NRZ-I or MLT-3 alone satisfy it individually?

Comment: It has already been stated. You can't fit the data rate through Cat5 copper cable if you don't use MLT-3. It could satisfy the requirement individually. NRZ-I is used for optical fibre so it makes sense to use same standard at the PHY attachment layer so you can have identical implementation up to the selection of copper or fiber PHY interface. NRZ-I also allows for clock recovery when receiving the signal, which is why it is used for fiber.